# How can I stop Gmail from freezing when I open emails?

Tags: gmail

Recently Gmail started freezing for 5-10 seconds after I open emails. It becomes completely unresponsive, no scrolling, no nothing. I can switch tabs and applications. I'm using Chrome and I haven't tested in other browsers but it's definitely happening on at least two computers.

Comment: Have you tried with a different browser? There's probably little you _can_ do, except perhaps have fewer messages for the app to try to display.

Comment: @AlE. I found an answer to this: disabling the people widget seems to fix it. Source: http://songzdev.quora.com/Gmail-slow-and-sometimes-freezing-Solution?srid=uUcK&share=1

Comment: @AlE. I tried to answer it myself but I don't have enough reputation yet so I have to wait 8 hours to post. You're welome to answer in the meantime if you'd like.

Comment: No, you found a solution. You should get the credit.

Answer (score 2):

Turning off the people widget in Gmail's settings fixes this.

[image: Go to your Gmail settings]

[image: Scroll down and select "Hide the people widget"]

Credit goes to Song Zheng for figuring this out and posting about it:
http://songzdev.quora.com/Gmail-slow-and-sometimes-freezing-Solution?srid=uUcK&share=1