# Gmail freezing after opening on multiple browsers

Tags: gmail

I'm encountering a strange issue with Gmail where it will freeze and crash the browser tab within a few seconds of accessing it (while logged in or after logging in).  It seems to be consistent across browsers and platforms — it happens in Chrome 40 and Internet Explorer 11 under Windows 8 on my personal laptop, and in Chrome 40 under Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop at work.

I managed to quickly access Settings and disable the People widget [as suggested here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/55265/7701), but it did not help.

Comment: How does it crash? What kind of message are you getting from the browser? In Chrome is it just crashing the one tab?

Comment: @Fogest I don't recall the IE error offhand but in Chrome the tab stops responding to all events, even scrolling, and shortly thereafter will display the "Aw, snap!" error page -- no details. It's just the one tab in either browser that crashes, nearly identical behavior.   **Edit:** I tried Firefox in search of a better error message, and got it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad that at least one of the browsers was able to give you a helpful error report to help you solve the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested in Firefox 37 under Ubuntu and finally got a useful error message:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>
> Script: `https://talkgadget.google.com/…`

It seems like it might be related to [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=964560).

Following [this](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/161823) I turned off Chat:

> 1. Click the **gear icon** and choose **Settings**.
> 2. Click the **Chat** tab.
> 3. Choose "Chat off."
> 4. Click **Save changes**.

That seems to have fixed the issue.